# Fail to mount NAS network drive

Tags: networking, pi-3b+, mount, storage, fstab

I am attempting to mount a network drive. Since I am experienced with raspbian I've asked a friend that is for help, but neither him or I have managed to succeed.

I'm, using a RPi-3b+ and a ReadyNas Nv+. My ReadyNas have two shares. Both have NFS turned on and the same settings.

My code in /etc/fstab looks like this:

```
10.0.1.6:/c/media   /mnt/nfs   nfs   _netdev,defaults,noatime,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=30,timeo=14,x-systemd.idle-timeout=1min  2 2
10.0.1.6:/USB/media2   /mnt/usb   nfs   _netdev,defaults,noatime,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=30,timeo=14,x-systemd.idle-timeout=1min  2 2
```

Despite that my RPI just connects to the /USB/media2 which is a USB-drive connected to my ReadyNAS.

I have also tried to mount manually with:

```
sudo mount 10.0.1.6:/c/media /mnt/nfs
```

That doesn't work either.

I've read through some treads regarding similar problems without finding a solution.

Now I'm all out of ideas, so I'm hoping that someone here can help me.

Comment: Seems that you have a pretty good handle on fstab options, but have you tried vers=1.0 as an additional option?

Comment: What do you get from a `showmount -e 10.0.1.6` command?

Answer (score 1):

There is not very much information you have given about error- and debug-messages. Look at the journal if you can find some messages belonging to mounting network shares:

```
rpi ~$ journalctl --boot --pager-end
```

What message do you get with

```
rpi ~$ sudo mount 10.0.1.6:/c/media /mnt/nfs
```

Try with verbose output

```
rpi ~$ sudo mount --verbose 10.0.1.6:/c/media /mnt/nfs
```

If you still can't find relevant messages you can try to use debug output. But this will give you a buch of messages. This could be confusing but maybe you see some lines telling you what's going wrong:

```
rpi ~$ sudo LIBMOUNT_DEBUG=all mount 10.0.1.6:/c/media /mnt/nfs
```